# How to upload your own profile picture for Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've browsed through many sources on how to upload your own profile picture (instead of Google's default avatars) for Google Play Games, but could not find any solution, unfortunately... Is there really no way to do that after the most recent Google Play Games update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, you are correct. There is no way to upload your own avatar.

Answer (score 0):

The account that was setup a year ago allowed you to put your own pic

Comment: Why was this option removed